# Wordpress theme didn't load as it was on local after uploading to live server

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

I hope someone will be able to help me on this particular problem.
I upload my website to a subdomain and after this live website is nothing like the one in my local. There are no nav menu or any other components only some icons and footer. I import my sql file to server it's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the basic steps in moving a wordpress site to a new server.

1. Upload files and db and set proper file permissions if not correct.
2. Change the `wp config` information with the new db credentials.
3. Change the options `site_url` and `home_url` in `yourdbprefix_options` table to the new websites url from your phpMyAdmin.
4. Login to the admin panel and click on the permalinks and save, which will update your `.htaccess` file.
5. Install the pluign called velvet url and update the remaining urls in the db from it's options.
   You are done with the migrations now if you haven't hardcoded the urls anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind that on local you had different urls than you have on prod. You will need to alter the DB and replace the urls to the new one.
Please read more on how to [Move/Migrate WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

You can use [this sql](https://gist.github.com/chuckreynolds/6032234) on your live DB to update the urls.

There are also a lot of great plugins that could help you with this.